# Semantic versioning and git branches

Tags: git, version-control, semantic-versioning

I have a master branch at **v1.0** and a develop branch that is **v1.1dev**.

I then make a new release branch from dev, and bump the version number from **v1.1dev** to **v1.1**, finish up, merge said release branch into master, and presto - **v1.1** is born at `master`.

But then, I merge the same release branch back into dev and so the dev branch is also **v1.1**.

Although this is technically true, I feel like dev it should always end in **dev** since, after all, it is the development version that is working toward the next real version.

---

So my question is:

- Does everyone dedicate a single commit on the dev branch to bump the version of their Dec code after merging in a release branch, or is there something I'm missing (a script, a methodology, a technique, etc.)?
- Also, is the above description generally representative of how people bump their version numbers?

**TL;DR:** **When should you bump version numbers in the various branches of a git-versioned project assuming semantic versioning?**

Comment: Depends. How are you implementing version numbers? In theory a checkout of a version number should only contain code at that version number not code at version ++

Comment: Well the only branch that gets actually tags is master. But I mean the version numbers in the project files... when do you update them? On the dev branch after merging release, or on the release branch after merging into master but before merging into dev?

Comment: The version numbers in the project files is meaningless to developers. They're only used to tell customers what version of software he's running. Developers should always refer to the tags. If the checkout is exactly at the tag then he has that version number. If it's ahead of the tag then he has version++. This is the only sane interpretation of "version". Otherwise two people with version 2.1 may have completely different code.

Comment: So basically no developer really cares what the version numbers in various project files indicate until a release branch is created. Is that about right?

Comment: Make a `v1.1` tag.  Let git-describe generate a version number for the dev branch which will include an abbreviated hash of HEAD from which you build.  Don't bother trying to add `-dev` suffixes; let `git-describe` do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Although this probably isn't an issue for you anymore now, you are correct when you say:

> ... it is always the development version that is working toward the next
>   real version...

When you branch your code, leave the branch version at v1.0. This will be the release branch, the codebase that goes into this release, that you patch if ever you have to bug fix or enhance this version in the future if the users can't upgrade to the next full version.

You can always merge changes from that branch back into master, but obviously not any code that defines the version number, which is normally in a config, property or build file anyway.

After branching, bump the version in the master to v1.1.x or v1.1-DEV or whatever you care to call it.